# Madza3 2008 can't remove headlight wiring harness

Tags: mazda, headlight, mazda-3

I have a 2008 Madza3 and I'm trying to replace a low-beam bulb (passenger side).  However, I can't get the wiring clip off of the bulb prongs.  I've tried pulling hard and wiggling it all directions for 10+ minutes and it won't come off.

Is there some kind of lubricant I can use to get this harness loose?

Comment: Usually a firm pull is required

Comment: Yeah tried that too.

Comment: unless it has melted on then it will come off...

Comment: Is there a tab that needs to be depressed to "unlock" the connector?

Comment: Yes I'm pressing the tabs and pulling/wiggling, just can't get it off.  Not much room too work due to antifreeze reservoir and wiper fluid tube in the way.  I've read about dielectric grease, is that OK to use?

Comment: is the tab fully releasing? you may need to use a small pick or screw driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grease can only be applied *before* you connect the socket.

You either have a melted plug, or it is just incredibly seized... which I’ve never seen one that stuck.

If it has shorted and melted on, you’re probably going to have to replace the plug/socket completely. If it has melted, you may be able to see some melting damage on the outside.

If you think it’s just stuck, you can try ***GENTLY*** knocking the plug with the end of a screwdriver (or similar small lightweight tool). But you have to be VERY careful not to hit it hard because you could easily break something. You can also pick up a can of electric motor cleaner/lubricant. They are lubricants that are formulated to be non-conductive. Final solution if it’s stuck, you can try gently heating the plug with a heat gun. Again, you have to be ***very careful*** that you don’t overheat it and heat it. If you do, then you’ll have to replace it.